# Quoting issue with pathFor in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I just can't get the quoting to work properly in my template. I know I could generate the link in the client side JavaScript, but I think it would make sense to do it directly in the template.

My code looks like below and my target is to make the div clickable:

```
<div class="thumbnail" onclick="window.location = {{pathFor 'viewSailboatAd' _id}}">
```

This renders:

```
<div class="thumbnail" onclick="window.location = /ads/sailboat/yXbWorY3295RdevnQ">
```

That won't work as we need quoting around the value like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail" onclick="window.location = '/ads/sailboat/yXbWorY3295RdevnQ'">
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works :

```
<div class="thumbnail" onclick="window.location = '{{pathFor "viewSailboatAd" _id}}'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not making the thumbnail an anchor in the first place ?

Bootstrap `.thumbnail` class plays nicely when used as a link.

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="{{pathFor "viewSailboatAd" _id}}">
  {{! ...}}
</a>
```